# Autocorrelation of the rectangular function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, signal-processing

Given the autocorrelation function of the signal "s":

$$r(k)=\sum_{t=-\infty}^{+\infty}{s(t)\cdot s(t+k)}$$

The autocorrelation of a rectangular function $\Pi$ (t/2) is a triangle formed by the vector:

$$(..., r_{-3}, r_{-2}, r_{-1}, r_0, r_1 r_2, r_3, ...) = (..., 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, ...)$$

Although the values of $\Pi$ (t/2) are the same between [-1, 1] with the function:

$$z(t)=\begin{cases}
1, |t|\le1/2\\
0, |t|\gt 1\\
\end{cases}$$

The autocorrelation is different, why?

Comment: Because the autocorrelation is $\sum_k\Pi(t/2)\Pi((t+k)/2)$, which is different from $\Pi(t/2)$.

Comment: I read your question as saying that the two functions are equal and yet they have different autocorrelation sequences. This of course doesn't make sense. You may want to explicitly define both functions and reword your question. (I also think their their is a missing "$/2$" from the definition of $z$).

Comment: I think because both functions are evaluated different, with t=2 I have Π(t=2/2) = Π(1) = 1 but with z(t=2) = 0. Autocorrelation is a consequence of this points discordance.